# org-mode filtering a table with org-babel

Tags: csv, emacs, org-mode, org-babel, org-table

To filter a table with org-mode in emacs I am using org-babel. However, my function does not quite work and I am not sure why. The following is the link to the zip file which contains the csv I am testing my function on: [source](http://www.unece.org/cefact/codesfortrade/codes_index.html). The csv is named **2014-1 SubdivisionCodes.csv**.

First I open the file with emacs and then highlight the entire region and run the command `org-table-create-or-convert` which transforms the CSV into an ORG table. Next I name the table using `org-babel` syntax: `#+tblname: un-states`

Immediately following is the entire table. I want to filter out the rows that are **states.** Here is my code for filtering the table by the value in the fourth column:

```
#+name: filter-un
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var tbl=un-states
(remove-if (lambda (row) (not (equal (cadddr row) "State"))) tbl)

#+end_src
```

I evaluate the function with `C-c C-c` and the results I get are:

```
#+results: filter-un
| AU | NSW | New South Wales   | State |
| AU | QLD | Queensland        | State |
| AU | SA  | South Australia   | State |
| AU | TAS | Tasmania          | State |
| AU | VIC | Victoria          | State |
| AU | WA  | Western Australia | State |
```

The data includes states in the United States of America, so we are clearly missing a lot of states. Why isn't my function working? What I immediately notice is that `AU` is the first set of rows for which there are states and they are all contiguous rows. So it appears that it stops working after this point.

- How can I get my function to work properly and include more states?

Thanks for all the help. I just started using `org-babel` a few hours ago and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what encoding the CSV file is in? I couldn't even manage to pass the converted org table to a src block and I suspect it's because of odd characters in the table.

Comment: I have no idea... It appears to have worked for me though.